# Express Fileupload only working on one router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So i'm in this situation where the route `/update-propic` in `user-router.js` has correct use of `express-fileupload` middleware but `/img/upload` in `image-host-router.js` has `req.files` to `null` (obv even when files are sent)

I've also discovered that the first router "used"(aka imported) in `server.js` gets access to `express-fileupload` but the other ones do not

this is my folder tree:

```
server/
├─ src/
│  ├─ routers/
│  │  ├─ image-host-routes.js
│  │  ├─ user-routes.js
├─ server.js
```

server.js

```js
...other requires
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");

// Init express
const app = express();

// Middlewares
app.use(fileUpload());
...other middlewares


// Login Routes
app.use(require("./src/routers/user-routes"));

// Blog Post Routes
app.use(require("./src/routers/blog-post-routes"));

// Comment Routes
app.use(require("./src/routers/comment-routes"));

// Image hosting routes
app.use(require("./src/routers/image-host-routes"));

const PORT = 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running on localhost:${PORT}`));
```

user-routes.js

```js
...other requires
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

//NOTE: no `use` middlewares present
router.post("/update-propic", checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.files); // Console logs correctly the `files` object
    } catch (err) {
        //
    }
});
```

img-host-routes.js

```js
const express = require("express");

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/img/upload", [checkAdmin], (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.files); // Logs `null`
    } catch (err) {
        //
    }
});
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: @Shubh oh i forgot to add it, I edited the post

Comment: Maybe is there something in your checkAdmin function that edit req object?

Comment: @Nicolò no it only contains a condition